# React Routing Image not found on redirect to a route

Tags: reactjs, react-router

#**Issue_Solved**
*Solution:*
Inside *package.json* file update-

```
"homepage": "."
```

to

```
"homepage": "https://www.exapmle.com/",
```

**Problem**
Every thing is working fine on locally but on production server/ hosting serve when I go landing page to another page the Navbar brand image not found.

image on landing page: https://dazzling-yonath-5559e4.netlify.app/static/media/sundarbanX-logo.12b02027.png

image on profile page: https://dazzling-yonath-5559e4.netlify.app/profile/static/media/sundarbanX-logo.12b02027.png

And import image on Navbar component is:

```
import LOGO from '../images/sundarbanX-logo.png';

<img onClick={()=>history.push('/')}  
   style={{cursor:'pointer',marginRight: 160 }} 
   src={LOGO} alt="logo" className={classes.logo} />
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Use ***require*** instead of ***import*** for importing images.

`const Logo = require('../images/sundarbanX-logo.png');`

Comment: I applied this one, but not working on the production